# How to mint multiple NFT token from Metaplex Candy Machine v2?

Tags: linux-mint, solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine

I am trying to mint multiple token (2 in my case) from one user click. I see in the metaplex JS library, there's one function called mintOneToken which allows us to mint one token at time. How can I implement the function which mints n token at one click of the user?

Answer (score 1):

that functionality is added in CMv2 cli [repo](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/blob/93eb1b82c0753eb8ddfe1aef82e25cc6639fe09d/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts#L860), and looks:

```
if (index < NUMBER_OF_NFTS_TO_MINT - 1) {
        log.info('minting another token...');
        await mintToken(index + 1);
      }
```

this statement in the discord community by **TonyBoyle.eth#0265** helped a lot to make sense of the problem

> The mint multiple in the CLI just loops a single transaction it's
> technically not multiple mint in one transaction

you can add this to the `onMint` function in the `Home.tsx` and tweak the frontend accordingly.